# Editing form options

Tags: forms

I am trying to edit the option names which appear in a drop down in a contact us form. I am really struggling to find where the ability to change this is located.

Attached is a screenshot of what I am talking about... If anyone could please offer some advice or help this would be much appreciated.

thank in advance
[image]

Comment: It can be on a template, which can only be found if you at least provide us the URL, without the domain. Or, it can be on a addon. Is there an addon like FreeForm instaled?

Comment: Yes, we are using freeform. But I am not too familiar with it, could you advise how to edit this? Or where I can go to find out how?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the field in your Control Panel. Log in to your CP and head to your FreeForm modules area.

```
Your Site -> CP Home -> Modules -> Freeform Pro -> Fields
```

Find your select field, and click on the edit button (it's a gear in the Edit column). At the bottom of the page, you have your `Field Options` section. There you can add/edit selections.

https://solspace.com/software/expressionengine/freeform/docs/control_panel/#fields

Comment: Did that fix your issue?